# Replication keeps popping up on SharePoint databases

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, database-replication

My typical discovery scenario:

We receive an alert that the transaction log is growing quickly. We are in Simple Recovery so I go to check it out. Log is already sized to 100GB and is at 80% capacity. I run the ["Whats using my log files"](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/DMV/71997/)  script from SQL Server Central and see that Replication is enabled on the database.

We do not set up replication, and I don't think Replication can be done on SharePoint content db's as Replication is not supported (requires PK on all tables). This has been occurring on random servers (about 5 so far, all within the past three weeks) and it only occurs on Content Databases.

sp_removedbreplication does not *always* work in removing the Replication either. We have found that we need to run the sp_removedbreplication, change all db owners to SA and reset Recovery Mode to Simple to completely eradicate any vestiges of this bug.

How would Replication be enabling itself? We have never set up Replication on these servers. There is no evidence of any type of Replication other than the 'log_reuse_wait_desc' from the DMV query and log growth. Any help on this ghost would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Someone has to be turning it on.  Sharepoint won't just enable replication by it self.

Setup a profiler trace for the replication stored procedures (I can get you some procedures names if needed) to see who is running them.  That or enable server auditing for the execution of these procedures.

Comment: Any proc names you could get me would be appreciated, thank you!

We restrict access to the servers to our team of four SQL engineers (none of us have set it up) and SQL and SharePoint Service accounts. Users can have access to the Service Accounts, but we cannot come up with how/why anyone would be doing this.

Comment: Some procedure names to trace for are: sp_replicationdboption, sp_adddistpublisher, sp_get_distrubutor.  Those would be the procedures needed to flip the flag on replication for a database.  Specifically the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if any [Change Data Capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645937.aspx) isn't used? CDC is based on transactional replication and would also cause log growth if the log reader agent is unable to keep up.

Comment: No CDC inproduction yet, and that is where are issues are coming from.